# ogr2ogr from MIF/MID to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, mapinfo, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert a .mif file to GeoJSON. I've got .mif, .mid and .dbf. But when I convert it, the properties included in .dbf are not rendered in the GeoJson file. The command I use is : `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON file.json file.mif`.

Is there something wrong with my command or do I need to add an option?

**More infos:**

With `ogrinfo` for the .dbf file :

```
ogrinfo car_m.dbf -so car_m
INFO: Open of `car_m.dbf'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: car_m
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=1913-10-18
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 2278213
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
id: String (21.0)
idINSPIRE: String (30.0)
idk: String (25.0)
ind_c: Real (16.4)
nbcar: Real (16.4)
```

And from .mid :

```
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 2278213
Extent: (48385.790000, 1620790.500000) - (1197778.210000, 2676806.350000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed",...]

idINSPIRE: String (30.0)
id: String (21.0)
```

Comment: Do I necessarily need to use a conversion to shp before the conversion to json, in order to merge the original dbf file with the dbf file containing ids from the first conversion ?

Comment: This might be better to ask in the http://gis.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: But as a quick note, I'm pretty sure the DBF is unrelated to the MID/MIF files They should be treated separately as two different file formats (and possibly different sets of data).

Comment: Thanks, I think so too. I converted the .mif in two steps, using .shp and merging the DBF file generated with the original one before converting to GeoJson.

Answer (score 0):

A solution : I converted the .mif in two steps, using .shp and merging the DBF file generated with the original one before converting to GeoJson, as relations are .mif/.mid and .shx/.shp/.dbf.